# On machine reboot via SNMP

Tags: monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring, system-monitoring

Is it possible to reboot a windows or a linux machine via SNMP?

Most of information I've found is related to the reload of the SNMP service itself, instead of host reboot.

Comment: I don't think an existing SNMP agent (Windows, Net-SNMP) supports that, but you can extend it with your own code.

Comment: you wanna have your machine shutdown when it receives the corresponding SNMP trap, right?